# run xterm and show file content using c

Tags: c, linux, terminal, raspberry-pi

I want to open terminal and cat a file (show its content) using c;
i got error from code below:

```
char * com = "xterm cat /home/user/Desktop/file.c";
system(com);
```

or even:

```
char * com = "/usr/bin/xterm /bin/cat /home/user/Desktop/file.c";
system(com);
```

thanks for any help;

Comment: What's the error?  Also, if you just cat it, it will likely terminate immediately after cat.  How about piping to less?

Comment: The first argument to xterm is the shell.  cat is not a shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your command to:

```
xterm -e less file.c
```